# Latency on aws (m1.large) with MongoDB 64b 2.x

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have deployed mongodb 64 bit 2.x version on aws m1.large instance.

I am trying to find best performance that mongo can give us on aws in-light of http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/tag/mongodb/ (and [mongodb read/write performance and mongo hosting in the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980949/mongodb-read-write-performance-and-mongo-hosting-in-the-cloud))

I have created one db with one collection i.e. user and inserted 100,000 records/json object (each json object size is 4KB) using random number as suffix to “user-“. Also, created index on user id.

Further, I set db profiler to log slow query taking 20ms or more. I have executed java program with 10 threads. Each java class generates user id with random number and finds it in user collection in infinite loop.  With such load I have observed latency in query/read up-to 60ms.

I also observed that when I run less number of threads say 3 or 4  (having query load on user collection 5K per second to find users) then I see no latency or less then 2ms latency.

I failed to understand why increasing load of finding user in collection is causing latency. I believe that mongo db can perform much more concurrent read then what I am trying and should not impact on performance as such.

One possibility I assume that would be - mongo is having performance issues if there are large queries executed on single collection like in our case, I expect to have 10K to 20K queries per second on single collection.

We would appreciate your thoughts / suggestion.

Comment: Are you using any indexes? What version of MongoDB? Do you use a library on Java? (like morphia) or just MongoDB?

Comment: Where are you measuring this latency?  From your java app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some information is missing - what is your disk configuration? The EBS may contribute to the latency if everything is persisted to disk.

Amazon had released a white paper with best practices on how to install mongo on EC2: [MongoDB on AWS](http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/AWS_NoSQL_MongoDB.pdf). Here's its description

> This whitepaper provides an overview of general best practices that apply to all major NoSQL systems and highlights one of popular NoSQL systems - MongoDB - and discusses how to best run it on the AWS cloud. It further examines different MongoDB configurations so you can optimize it for performance, durability, and security.